# How to change a date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date in following format:

```
13 Dec,2021 12:59:58
```

and I want to change it into:

```
13-12-2021
```

pls suggest some fix

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There are a huge number of questions about [parsing a string to a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+parse+a+date+string), and probably just as many on [how to format a date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date). Try something, and if you have trouble, post what you've tried, what you're trying to achieve and what you actually get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it do a `Date`, get the make a string out of the components.

The month needs to add 1 since for some reason, months are zero-indexed (January == 0, February == 1, ..., December == 11)

```js
const dateString = "13 Dec,2021 12:59:58";

const getNewString = (dateString) => {
  const date = new Date(dateString);
  return `${date.getDate()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getFullYear()}`;
}

console.log(getNewString(dateString));
```

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const oldDate = "13 Dec,2021 12:59:58";

const newDate = new Date(oldDate);

console.log(newDate.getDate() + "-" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + newDate.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to do this.

```js
console.log(moment('13 Dec,2021 12:59:58').format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```